# R) Seurat: grouping samples

Tags: r, seurat

I am analyzing six single-cell RNA-seq datasets with Seurat package.

These 6 datasets were acquired through each different 10X running, then combined with batch effect-corrected via Seurat function "FindIntegrationAnchors".
Meanwhile, among the 6 datasets, data 1, 2, 3 and 4 are "untreated" group, while data 5 and 6 belongs to "treated" group.
I merged all the 6 datasets together with batch-corrected, but I also need to compare features of "untreated" vs "treated".

How can I group data 1,2,3 and 4 into "untreated group", and data 5 and 6 into "treated group", and then perform downstream analysis?

Thanks.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Maybe also have a look here?: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick and dirty way to do this, is to add the information *before merging* the Seurat objects:

```
...
so_samples[[1]]@meta.data$treatment <- "control"
so_samples[[2]]@meta.data$treatment <- "control"
so_samples[[3]]@meta.data$treatment <- "control"
so_samples[[4]]@meta.data$treatment <- "control"
so_samples[[5]]@meta.data$treatment <- "treated"
so_samples[[6]]@meta.data$treatment <- "treated"
...
anchors <- FindIntegrationAnchors(object.list = so_samples, dims = 1:20)
so_all_samples <- IntegrateData(anchorset = anchors, dims = 1:20)
```

In general, it would be better to load such meta data from a file and join it to the seurat object without such error-prone copy-paste code. Also note that it is in general a bad idea to modify R S4 objects (those where you can access elements with `@`) like this, but the functions provided to modify Seurat objects provided by the Seurat package are so cumbersome to use that I doubt they will ever change the underlying data structure.

Comment: It successfully worked! Thank you for your generous help! @jan-glx